# Getting Errors on the Hooks and Step definition file for the dot net 4.6 framework and specflow 3.9.8

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019, specflow, gherkin

I am getting the below errors in my code in the Hooks file and Step definition file while working on the .net 4.6 framework(Visual Studio 2019). Please let me know if I missed any of the specflow packages. If I  # using TechTalk.SpecFlow; it gets highlighted in red. Please let me know if I am missing assembly reference. Do I need to install any other specflow package?

**Errors:**

`Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'GivenAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'BeforeScenario' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'BindingAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Binding' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).Error CS0103 The name 'ScenarioStepContext' does not exist in the current context`

**Also attaching the packages list:**

SpecFlow version is 3.9.8, SpecFlow.MsTest version is 3.9.8, SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation version is 3.9.8 and targetFramework is net46

Do I need to install any other specflow package?

Comment: Using the below assembly references:

using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Xml;
using RestSharp;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

Comment: I don't know Specflow, but perhaps it's a version conflict. In your title you mention a lower version than your packages. So you might want to downgrade them to 3.9.1